# Why is MySQL showing 'using where' in the 'extra' column?

Tags: mysql

I have  a very simple query which really needs to be as fast as possible...

The query is:

```
select users.userid, users.firstname, users.lastname
       from users_table users   
       where userid IN(1,4,6)
```

userid set as the primary key...

EXPLAIN returns the following:

```
id  |select_type|table|type |possible_keys|key    |key_len|ref |rows|Extra
1   |SIMPLE     |users|range|PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|4      |NULL|3   |Using where
```

Now, I was under the impression that 'Using where' is a bad thing?

Can anybody explain why I might be seeing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, the where is the only thing it can use.  It looks like it's using a primary key due to the `IN` clause being direct comparison to an indexed field (in this case your pk) so it don't get much better than this!  Actually, it's impossible to get better than this...

Comment: I see, for some reason I had in my head that anytime I see 'using where' rather than 'using index' it is a bad thing.  Thanks for the answer.  Being primarily a UI designer/front end coder trying to learn back end stuff is quite frustrating! :)

Comment: I'll award you the answer as soon as I am able. +1 as it the most complete answer despite AndreKR also correctly stating that is is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok to have "Using where" in MySQL because of [this issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30733). Check the `key`column to see if the key is actually used.